# How to fix apache restart

Tags: apache-httpd

We've setup [Uptime Robot](https://uptimerobot.com/) and noticed that one of our server apache service has gone away and restarted, i've found error logs as shown below. any idea what should i do with server configuration i have fully access to server

Linux version : CentOS 7.1

```
[Sun Mar 18 03:38:57.748759 2018] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 8715] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Mar 18 03:38:57.749478 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 8715] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Mar 18 03:38:57.757017 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8715] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Mar 18 03:38:57.796338 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8715] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.4.16 SVN/1.7.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 18 03:38:57.796360 2018] [core:notice] [pid 8715] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:01.492462 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8715] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:12.880639 2018] [fcgid:error] [pid 9246] FastCGI process 9250 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:12.880733 2018] [fcgid:error] [pid 9246] FastCGI process 9252 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:12.880750 2018] [fcgid:error] [pid 9246] FastCGI process 9254 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:12.880755 2018] [fcgid:error] [pid 9246] FastCGI process 9256 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:12.880760 2018] [fcgid:error] [pid 9246] FastCGI process 9257 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:12.880765 2018] [fcgid:error] [pid 9246] FastCGI process 9259 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:12.880771 2018] [fcgid:error] [pid 9246] FastCGI process 9297 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/multiwordpress/public_html/uae] does not exist
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:14.014337 2018] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 8715] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:14.015086 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 8715] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:14.022805 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8715] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:14.062739 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8715] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.4.16 SVN/1.7.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:14.062761 2018] [core:notice] [pid 8715] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:17.317788 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8715] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:28.702785 2018] [fcgid:error] [pid 9947] FastCGI process 9951 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:28.702961 2018] [fcgid:error] [pid 9947] FastCGI process 9957 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/multiwordpress/public_html/uae] does not exist
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:29.831593 2018] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 8715] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:29.832364 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 8715] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:29.839686 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 8715] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:29.877180 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8715] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.4.16 SVN/1.7.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 18 03:39:29.877201 2018] [core:notice] [pid 8715] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: This is either a `config` or compile issue with any number of the modules included and how they are loaded. At the core of the issue, those two modules are already load (well, that was clear from the error message), and you need to work out where the modules are being loaded twice from. Personally, the first two places I would check are the main Apache config and the PHP config.

Comment: does warning comparable to errors? i don't think this would be the cause, any other suggestion?